# Automating Google Ads API Refresh Token Generation and Renewal

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-ads-api, refresh-token

I'm using the Google Ads API to retrieve information from Google Ads campaigns. Initially, I manually generated a new refresh token by following specific steps to obtain an authorization code using a designated Google ID. Subsequently, I sent a CURL request with that code to generate a refresh token. Now, I aim to automate the entire process to convert the script, responsible for fetching Google Ads campaign data, into a full-time scheduler by automating the generation and renewal of the refresh token. Unfortunately, I'm encountering difficulties in achieving this. Is there a specific code or method available to accomplish the aforementioned task?

I would like to obtain the process and code for the aforementioned issue.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the difficulties you're facing ? Do you actually use the refresh token in your python code until it expires ? If so, you could try refreshing it once you got a 400 or 401 response.

Comment: Refreshing a token is as simple as calling an endpoint. I wrote an [article](https://www.jhanley.com/blog/google-oauth-2-0-testing-with-curl-refresh-access-token/) showing how. However, don't use user credentials in backend systems. Tokens can be invalidated (typically a week or two) and require user interaction to authenticate. Use a service account instead.